# How to know how many elements are overlapping and change their width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have 3 buttons in a flexbox in ONE table cell. The thing is I want to adjust the width of each button so that the buttons fill the horizontal width 100% (as much as they can). The problem is if I don't use flexbox, they overlap and the sizes don't adjust (cant see all buttons). However, if I use flexbox, since it is one cell, all the buttons shrink dynamically EVEN IF they are NOT overlapping in the y axis (it is a 42rem height cell, see picture below).

**Here is a photo of the problem:**

[image: Image showing the problem]

In the photo the red cell under the Monday column should be at full width and it is not.

**My Question is**: Can I have a way to dynamically change these widths (max-width didnt work) ONLY if they are overlapping. If they do not overlap they should fit the whole width. The caveat is I am going to be dynamically adding more events as time goes so I can just say put this one button at 50% because soon it may need to be 33%.

**Alternatively**: Is there a way to know exactly how many overlap, so I can just use JavaScript to readjust every time something is added (less nice).

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/samuel-solomon/pen/oNbKeRm?editors=1100
Note: I want to keep the y-position (it is for a calendar, so it represents the time)

```css
.day_Block {
  position: relative;
}

.flexbox_Edits {
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 42rem;
}

.event_Button {
  border-width: 2px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-style: inset solid solid;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-self: stretch;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}

.event_Button_Text {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 550;
  letter-spacing: 0.06rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 0.8em !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="container on_Left from_Top table-responsive">
  <table class="calendar mt-5" id="calendar_Table">
    <thead class="masthead">
      <tr>
        <th class="time_Col days"></th>
        <th>
          <str>Monday</span>
        </th>
        <th><span>Tuesday</span></th>
        <th><span>Wednesday</span></th>
        <th><span>Thursday</span></th>
        <th><span>Friday</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="calendar_Body">
      <tr id="Time">
        <td class="time_Col">
          <div class="time_Block">8am</div>
          <div class="time_Block">9am</div>
          <div class="time_Block">10am</div>
          <div class="time_Block">11am</div>
          <div class="time_Block">12pm</div>
          <div class="time_Block">1pm</div>
          <div class="time_Block">2pm</div>
          <div class="time_Block">3pm</div>
          <div class="time_Block">4pm</div>
          <div class="time_Block">5pm</div>
          <div class="time_Block">6pm</div>
          <div class="time_Block">7pm</div>
          <div class="time_Block">8pm</div>
          <div class="time_Block">9pm</div>
        </td>
        <td class="day_Block">
          <div class="d-flex flexbox_Edits" id="M">
            <button class="btn event_Button_Text event_Button event_Button_CS_2" style="height: 12rem; top: 0rem; background-color: rgb(83, 94, 235);">M8:00 - 12:00<br>CS 2<br></button>

            <button class="btn event_Button_Text event_Button event_Button_CS_1" style="height: 21rem; top: 18rem; background-color: rgb(254, 44, 84);">M2:00 - 9:00<br>CS 1<br></button>
            <button class="btn event_Button_Text event_Button event_Button_CS_1" style="height: 21rem; top: 18rem; background-color: rgb(19, 202, 145);">M2:00 - 9:00<br>CS 1<br></button>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="day_Block">
          <div class="d-flex flexbox_Edits" id="T"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="day_Block">
          <div class="d-flex flexbox_Edits" id="W"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="day_Block">
          <div class="d-flex flexbox_Edits" id="R"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="day_Block">
          <div class="d-flex flexbox_Edits" id="F"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using display flex and also top:18rem. I think top value is set to display at appropriate time position. This top value is moving them down but their original position is in the first row.
I think you can divide the buttons into sub divisions based on the timeslots they occupy and put display flex to those.

```html
<div class="d-flex flexbox_Edits" id="M">
  <button class="btn event_Button_Text event_Button event_Button_CS_2" style="height: 12rem; top: 0rem; background-color: rgb(83, 94, 235);">M8:00 - 12:00<br>CS 2<br></button>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flexbox_Edits" id="M">
  <button class="btn event_Button_Text event_Button event_Button_CS_1" style="height: 21rem; top: 18rem; background-color: rgb(254, 44, 84);">M2:00 - 9:00<br>CS 1<br></button>
  <button class="btn event_Button_Text event_Button event_Button_CS_1" style="height: 21rem; top: 18rem; background-color: rgb(19, 202, 145);">M2:00 - 9:00<br>CS 1<br></button>
</div>
```

You can check in this modified code pen of yours.
https://codepen.io/rohinikumar4073/pen/MWKNXzP?editors=1100

Comment: The codepen you have seems to make the 8am timeslot huge and also the M2:00-9:00 is not in the right position?

Comment: I am also adding the buttons dynamically with javascript. This means that I can possibly have more events added. The problem with your solution is that it would not work as there is no way to differentiate those two flexboxes. I Also would have to rearrange the flexbox as I add and remove events